# Accessing many to many data in class-based detail view with models in different apps Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-related-manager

I have two models related via `ManyToMany` relationship, but they are located in separate apps. I am trying to load details of one model then adding the `manytomany` field in the template but the conventional way is not working. Here is my code so far:

models.py (listings app)

```
from listing_admin_data.models import PropertyFeatures


class Property(models.Model):
    ....
    property_features = models.ManyToManyField(PropertyFeatures)
    ....
```

models.py (listing_admin_data app)

```
class PropertyFeatures(models.Model):
    ....
    feature_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ....
```

views.py

```
class PropertyDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Property
    context_object_name = 'property'
```

Then in the template, I am trying to do this, but getting empty list, yet I have data.

```
<h3>Property Features</h3>
<ul class="amenities-list">
    {% for feature in property.property_features.all %}
        <li>{{ feature.feature_name }}</li>
        {% empty %}
        <li>Property has no features!</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I tried this intentionally: `<p>{{ property.property_features }}</p>`
And upon loading I get: `listing_admin_data.PropertyFeatures.None` on the browser.
The other fields directly related to the object loaded are working fine, like `{{ property.price }}`, while those from `ForeignKey` are also working fine, i.e. `{{ property.listing.listing_title }}`. Is inter-apps model relationship handled the same way in Django or it has a special treatment?

Comment: What does `{{ property.property_features }}` give?

Comment: It gives `listing_admin_data.PropertyFeatures.None` as described above in the question.

Comment: What about `{{ property.property_features.all }}`?

Comment: `{{ property.property_features.all }}` gives `<QuerySet []>`

Comment: Sorry, Danielo asked what I meant to type.  So that means you've nothing in the queryset which is why you're getting none

Comment: Actually, from admin backend, the related property has property features. I really don't know why nothing is loaded. Could the `model's` location in different apps be an issue?

Comment: Actually, now it is working. It is true the feature list was empty, tried editing from backend and now it is returning the list as it should: `<QuerySet [<PropertyFeatures: Built-in wardrobes>, <PropertyFeatures: Alarm System>, <PropertyFeatures: Intercom>, <PropertyFeatures: Ensuite>]>`. Thanks for your insights.